# SnapKit get width while setting left and right

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a UITextView, and its width is setting like this:

```
mytextView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.left.equalTo(self.leftView.snp_right).offset(10)
        make.right.equalTo(self.rightView.snp_left).offset(10)
}
```

I need to dynamically change the height of UITextView based on its content. And I am going to calculate the height of the view by using

```
func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize
```

But by only setting make.left and make.right, how can I get the width of the the textview?

Comment: What is snp in snp_right/left?

Comment: I am using SnapKit for autolayout, you can find it here:https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit